# What are the Visual Studio Load Test supported and unsupported Protocols?

Tags: visual-studio-2015

Can i use any of these protocols TCP, HTTP, AJAX, FTP for Visual Studio Load Test? Is there any unsupportability of protocol by Visual Studio Load Test using VSTS 2015

Answer (score 0):

If you can create a Unit test to connect to an interface. Then you can use it for load testing.  Anything you can code inside a unit test can be turned into a load test. So, yes all of those protocols and many more are supported.